# Limitar cantidad de elementos li creados

Tags: jquery

Estoy consultando de una lista cuando elementos tiene con el `length` para luego meterlo en un `for` y crear `div` de acuerdo a la cantidad.

Es decir, si hay 2 elementos en la lista me crea 2 `li`.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="thumbs">
  <li>1 item</li>
  <li>2 item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="dots">

</ul>

<script>
var numThumbs = $(".thumbs li").length;
for(let i=0; i < numThumbs; i++){
  $(".dots").append("<li class='nav-dot'></li>");
}
</script>
```

Pero pasa que no sé porqué la instrucción se repite tantas veces. Me salen mas `li` de la cuenta.

Puse un `console.log("hola")` para ver y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Captura de pantalla de la consola de javascript mostrando la repetición de 10 veces el mensaje "hola"]

Se está repitiendo 10 veces. Entonces me gustaría saber si alguna forma de limitarlo a 1 solamente.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: pues si, ahi esta las 2 listas html.

Comment: Con el ejemplo que pusiste tu codigo funciona bien, solo te falto el punto antes de `dots`

Comment: si asi funciona bien, pero lo que sucede es como estoy trabajando en un ambiente y no se le que esta pasando por atras para que se repita tanto. Entonces por eso la idea como de limitarlo. Por ej: thumbs ya la trae por defecto, la nueva que agregue custom es la dots.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir dónde poner exactamente en tu código el `console.log("hola");` y el trozo de código que agrega los `li` nuevos? No consigo reproducir tu problema. Edito tu pregunta para poder reproducir tu problema, así podrás ver que el código funciona adecuadamente.

Comment: Voto cierre por no poder reproducirse el problema. Han pasado 5 días y no se han aportado respuestas a los comentarios publicados.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la clave para resolver lo que planteas es que, por ejemplo, repita como máximo N elementos. Si por ejemplo el máximo es 5, repetiría los 5 primeros elementos del original si los hubiera.

Si estoy en lo cierto, puedes hacerlo así...

```js
const maxThumbs = 5,
      numThumbs = $(".thumbs li").length;
for(let i=0; i < Math.min(numThumbs,maxThumbs) ; i++){
    $(".dots").append("<li class='nav-dot'>a</li>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="thumbs">
      <li>1 item</li>
      <li>2 item</li>
      <li>3 item</li>
      <li>4 item</li>
      <li>5 item</li>
      <li>6 item</li>
      <li>7 item</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="dots">

    </ul>
```

Se trata de definir un máximo de repeticiones, y después hacer el `for` hasta el valor mínimo entre ese tope y el número de elementos que haya en la lista original.

Espero que te valga así